# How to get list of changed files since last build in Jenkins/Hudson with git/gerrit

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

Is there any mechanism I can get the changes between two builds in Jenkins in git/gerrit environment, I am getting all changes using all changes plugin, but I want get a nice set of change between build say 1 and 2, and send an email.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to its name, [Changes Since Last Success](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Changes+Since+Last+Success+Plugin) plugin has a lot of useful options, not just "since last success". It does limit everything to "since [something] to *current*"